# Laravel Multi-Tenant Multi-Database Multi-Domain - Problem with default route

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, saas

I'm studying about multi-tenant with Laravel and I'm having a problem with the routes. The main application works fine, however the main client domain (route / ) returns the 401 error configured in the middleware I created, but the other routes (login, register, etc) work perfectly.

If I put a prefix on the main application routes, then the / client route works normally, but I need the main application not to have a prefix since I want to use it to create the service submission and hiring system.

Anyone who has knowledge on this subject and can take a look at my code and help me find out why only the route is returning this error I will be very grateful.

```
If i access app.mydefaultapp  works
If i access app.myclientapp doesn't works
If i access app.myclientapp/login(or any other route) works
```

https://pastebin.com/bHHux9sY

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a Provider with the same Middleware identification logic, and when accessing the main domain it dynamically loads the routes of the main domain.

```
$manager = app(ManagerTenant::class);
    if ($manager->domainIsMain())
    {
        $this->registerTenantRoutes();
        $this->registerTenantAdminRoutes();
    }
```

https://pastebin.com/20SCsgfL